# Flot chart display in an unexpected way

Tags: javascript, flot

I have the following javascript code to create a bar chart:

```
    var data1 = [
    {
        label: user1_name,
        data: user1_data,
        bars: {
            show: true,
            fill: true,
            lineWidth: 1,
            order: 1,
            fillColor:  "#6783b7"
        },
        color: "#6783b7"
    },
    {
        label: user2_name,
        data: user2_data,
        bars: {
            show: true,
            fill: true,
            lineWidth: 2,
            order: 2,
            fillColor:  "#4fcdb7"
        },
        color: "#4fcdb7"
    },

];
$("#flot-bar").length && $.plot($("#flot-bar"), data1, {
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [ticks]
    },
    yaxis: {

    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: false,
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    legend: {
        labelBoxBorderColor: "none"
    },
    series: {
        shadowSize: 1
    },
    tooltip: true,
})
```

Where user1_name = `"Mette Kjerbye "`

user1_data =

```
Array[4]
0: 1
1: 10
3: 0
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
```

user2_data =

```
    Array[4]
0: 2
1: 9
3: 2
length: 4
```

ticks = `[0, "Mette Kjerbye ", 1, "Kamilla Utoft Kristensen "]`

Now this does generate a chart however it looks kinda odd:

[image]

if you looks at the picture you will see that only `Mette Kjerbye` is display in the X axis legend and that the two bars are far apart.

Can anyone tell me what i am missing in my options?

Comment: Could you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Code snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) which shows your problem?

Comment: Btw: Your tick array has x values 0 and 1, but your data has x values 1 and 2.

Comment: Doesn't look like your data is in the correct format.  `ticks` for example is an array of arrays, `[[0, "Mette Kjerbye "], [1, "Kamilla Utoft Kristensen "]]`, your series data should also be array  of arrays...